# How to implement Rabbitmq client for NodeMCU in Lua

Tags: lua, rabbitmq, esp32, nodemcu

Can anybody help me in implementing rabbitmq client for ESP32(NodeMCU Lua)..?
Actually I'm having little knowledge on MQTT I've implemented basic publish and subscribe with Mosquitto broker on ESP32(NodeMCU Lua) which is already available in NodeMCU documentation.
Now I want to work with Rabbitmq but I don't know how to work with that, where to start and there's no much available resources for guiding how to use rabbitmq in NodeMCU Lua and any efforts towards this will be appreciated.

I'm having doubts like can I able to implement with the existing API's (module) provided by NodeMCU (https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/dev-esp32/modules/mqtt) or need to implement a dedicated client for Rabbitmq please help me to get solution for this maze and also please provide me any sources.

Comment: If RabbitMQ talks standard MQTT - which it does through [a plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/mqtt.html) - then you should be able to use our MQTT module as-is.

Comment: Hi @MarcelStör Thank you for your valuable replay. could you please tell me how to use it as-is because I can't able to understand that rabbitmq mqtt plugin or please provide me any detailed source is there.

Comment: I don't know more than what is in that documentation; never ran RabbitMQ myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abhi - if this is still an issue for you then perhaps I can help:

- you do NOT need any RabbitMQ plugins or other code on the NodeMCU device.
- you DO need your NodeMCU firmware compiled to include the MQTT module.
- you DO need to enable the rabbitmq_mqtt plugin on your server.

For help with NodeMCU stuff look at https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/release/modules/mqtt/

And for the RabbitMQ plugin: https://www.rabbitmq.com/mqtt.html#enabling-plugin

Cheers
Sean

Comment: Hi @Sean Phelan Thank you, I did same thing with MarcelStör's idea and it's worked for me but I forgot to update. Anyway thanks again